# lacquer finish/a lacquer finish/the lacquer finish [article usage]

Tags: articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles, zero-article

I've just read an article about lacquer finish (or should I say ***a lacquer finish*** here?), and the use of articles is a bit confusing.

The headline uses the indefinite one, which is kind of clear because we make an introduction:

> What Are the Benefits of a Lacquer Finish?

Then it goes like this:

> The lacquer finish is also relatively long lived, resistant to
> staining, and won't oxidize and become brittle.

I assume we can use the definite article after the heading featuring 'a', but the following sentence uses 'the':

> In addition, a lacquer finish does not feature color or tone changes
> as it dries, thereby allowing the carpenter to better judge the finish
> from the moment of application.

Why is it so?

After that, the author (a native speaker I believe) uses the definite article in two consecutive sentences:

> Another noteworthy advantage of the lacquer finish is its longevity
> and general wear resistance. ...
>
> ... The lacquer finish also resists cracking due to heat modulation or
> wood shrinkage.

But after that it's the indefinite one again!

> One of the attractive features of a lacquer finish from a carpenter's
> perspective is its color and tone stability throughout the drying
> cycle.

The article also features a couple of pictures that have the following captions:

> Lacquer finish dries quickly, and its color stays the same, wet or dry.
>
> A lacquer finish allows for easier maintenance of furniture pieces.

I suppose we can omit articles in headlines and titles, but is it correct to alter them like that?

Comment: The unvarnished truth:  Because English.

Comment: Anarthrous singular usage is not one of the methods English uses to state a generic. *Lacquer finishes are ....* / *A lacquer finish is ....* / [and possibly, but rarer] *The lacquer finish is* ....]. But not **Lacquer finish is*. // Either of 'Lacquer finishes' or 'A lacquer finish'  is a good start to introduce the topic / subtopic. But after it has been mentioned, identified ['Another noteworthy advantage of the lacquer finish' ...], the definite article is certainly licensed (though the generic forms are equally acceptable here).